# Dynamically register a Vuex plugin?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

How can I register a plugin dynamically to vuex. The documentation says I can dynamically register modules etc. but not how to do it for a plugin.

Is including the plugin at store creation the only method to add plugins?
I was hoping for a `store.use(plugin)` or `vuex.use(plugin)`…

Comment: Vuex stores are reactive way for that. but i think this will effect to web pack . try to use native methods.  https://codesandbox.io/s/jp4xmzl0xy

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A Vuex plugin is simply a function that receives the store as the only argument, and is invoked in the Store instance during construction.

To apply a plugin after a Store has been constructed, you just need to invoke the plugin function and pass the Store instance to that function:

```es6
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import Plugin from 'plugin'

const store = new Vuex.Store({ ... })

// Later on
Plugin(store)
```

Keep in mind that some plugins simply may not work correctly with already-constructed Store instances. Your milage may vary.